# Fastest method to recognize an all-NULL string in python

Tags: python, performance

Suppose a performance-critical code section reads equally-sized data block from a disk file. How can I detect an all-null string/data block in the shortest time possible?

This is my current code:

```
# options.blocksize = 1024*1024
f, dummy = do_open(dev, 'r')
zeroblock = '\0'*options.blocksize
while True:
    block = f.read(options.blocksize)
    if not block:
        break
    if block == zeroblock:
        csum = "0000"
```

As you can see, I am comparing an all-null block to the ones read from the file. This method works but, for large blocks, it spend considerable time in the comparison.

I also tried counting NULL occurrences:

```
# options.blocksize = 1024*1024
f, dummy = do_open(dev, 'r')
zeroblock = '\0'*options.blocksize
while True:
    block = f.read(options.blocksize)
    if not block:
        break
    if block.count('\0') == options.blocksize:
        csum = "0000"
```

but it is even slower than the first method.

Any suggestion on how to improve performance?
Thanks.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? `.blocksize` I'm not familiar with, but I don't see what's wrong with the question

Comment: @roganjosh I fixed the indentation, thanks for noticing

Comment: Have you seen this https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/6f0ea4/fastest_way_to_determine_if_a_1k_bytearray/ and links from it?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if block == zeroblock:` try `if not sum(block):`. Adding zeros together should be very fast.

`if not any(block):` should be about as fast, but for sufficiently large blocks may perform better. (It shortcuts on the first nonzero.)

Note that doesn't work on normal unicode strings, only bytestrings `b''` because bytestring iterators return ints instead of 1-character strings. This means you have to `open()` the file in binary mode with `'rb'` instead of just `'r'`.

---

Python 2 doesn't have `bytes`. The old `str` type it uses instead was byte-based, but the iterator returns length-1 strings instead of integers like we want. So you'll want to use byte arrays instead in Python 2. Either upgrade your Python, or try something like this.

```
from array import array

f, dummy = do_open(dev, 'rb')
while True:
    block = array('B')  # 'B' means bytes. (Actually "unsigned char" in C.)
    try:
        block.fromfile(f, options.blocksize)
    except EOFError:  # Fewer bytes were left than blocksize.
        pass # Remaining bytes were still appended though.
    if not block:
        break
    if not any(block):  # sum() might be faster depending on blocksize.
        csum = "0000"
```

You don't need the try/except part if you know the file divides into blocksize evenly.

---

You might also try `array('L')` to load the data as unsigned longs instead of as bytes. This would probably quarter the number of iterations required by `sum` as the array would contain fewer (bigger) elements, but you'd have to make sure that aligns with your blocksize.

Comment: It does not appear to work... The first approach returns (as expected): "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'". The second one never identifies an all null string (it always returns true).

Comment: @shodanshok Make sure you open the file with `rb` to get bytestrings instead of unicode strings.

Comment: This works only for unsigned data (which includes chars) but for signed data, also non-zero elements can sum to zero.

Comment: @JohanL `any()` would still work in that case, yes? And Python's `bytes` type (the b-strings) always contain unsigned bytes.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I was only considering the `if not sum(block):` statement. Bytes are, as you say, unsigned, but the question also mentions data in general.

Comment: I tried appending `'rb'` to my `open` but the results did not change: `block` is read as a `str` and `sum(block)` fails with a type error. Maybe it is python-version related? Thanks.

Comment: @shodanshok it is version related. Python2 doesn't have the new bytes type. See my edit.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the effort. I'll try it as soon as possible. +1

Comment: Mmm... ok, it does work but it is *three* order of magnitude *slower* than the naive compare method. To be more precise, it is the `block.fromfile` call which read very slowly (I think due to lack of or insufficient buffering). As I said, it is an interesting approach, so my +1 is well deserved ;)